# Terraform replace regex

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform template file. `example.tpl`

And I would like to remove all the lines that start with `#`

I have 3 lines that start with `#` in the top of the file:

```
# Comment1
# Comment2
# Comment3
<Content of the file>
```

I'm trying to do the replacement in the following manner:

```
data "template_file" "example" {
  template = "${replace(file("example.tpl"),"/^#.*\n/", "")}"
}
```

And for some reason in the rendered output I can see that only one the first line is removed.

I.e. I'm getting

```
# Comment2
# Comment3
<Content of the file>
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `replace(file("example.tpl"),"/^#.*\n/g", "")`.

Comment: Nope, seems like with `g` it doesn't remove any lines at all

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(file("example.tpl"),"/(?m)^#.*(?m)\n/", "")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `^` and `$` only matches beginning and end of document, you should use flag `m` to change this - https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/regex.html#matching-flags

Applying this:

```
data "template_file" "example" {
  template = "${replace(file("example.tpl"),"/^#.*\n/m", "")}"
}
```

It is possible that you can replace `\n` with, `$`.